# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 207 Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am new with laravel and I have a problem and I can not solve it. I have already seen the official documentation as well as some other questions right here but I can not solve it.

What I want to achieve is an update to the database, but as I'm not successful I'm simply trying to send a response with some message that I can not get it to work either.
I am trying it through ajax, I want to send information to the controller and there the update is performed, in this case it responds a simple message ...

This is my route:

```
Route::patch('pdv/inventario-transferencia/{store}/{idTran}/update', 'InventoryController@editQtTemp');
```

This is my code that is executed by pressing a button:

```
$('.btn-qtyTemp').click(function(e) {
    //ADAN
    e.preventDefault();
    id_el = $(this).data('id');
    valInput = document.getElementById('input-'+id_el).value;      
    el = id_el.replace("quantityTemp-", "");
    var  valueIdTran = parseInt(el);
    if(!isNaN(valueIdTran)) {

         $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-XSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'patch',
            url: location.pathname + '/' + el + '/update',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                isValInput: valInput
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                console.log('entrando');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Todo Correcto'+data.isId);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Algo anda mal'+data.isId);
            }
        });
    }
    //      alert('id_el: '+id_el+' el: '+el+' value: '+valueIdTran+' val: '+valInput);
});
```

And this is the function of the controller:

```
public function editQtTemp(Request $request, $store, $idTran) {


       if ($request->ajax()) {

            $this->validate($request, [
                'isValInput' => 'required'
            ]);

            //
            $isValInput = $request->input('isValInput');

            if ($isValInput=='') {
                # code...
                return response()->json([
                    'isId' => ['Valor Invalido']
                ], 422);
            }
            else {
                return response()->json([
                    'isId' => [$isValInput]
                ], 200);
            }
        }
}
```

The error that appears to me is the following:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 207:


    in RouteCollection.php line 207
    at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 194
    at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 142
    at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 729
    at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 652
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 628
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 214
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 36
    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
    at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
    at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
    at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
    at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 100
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 115
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 52
```

I have no idea what may be happening, I have done this in pure PHP but with laravel I am having many problems ... Thanks

Comment: In English, please, or try your question at https://es.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Hi - you may want to try this question on https://es.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: However, from the code and error message, you may just need to pass a `_method` of patch, since it seems to be sending it as POST. See https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#form-method-spoofing

Comment: Can you please post the relevant part of your routes file? Are you sure that the endpoint is set to receive a PATCH request?